# How to find lost account login email address

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I got logged off Minecraft and couldn't remember which email I used to log back on. So I purchased another account. I was messing around with the `launcher_profiles.json` file by reading it in Windows 10 notepad and I read my new email among the data. I tried to do a system restore to read the file before it was written to my new account and still had the old data, but system restore is off by default in Windows 10.

Is there another log file that will contain all the emails that I used to successfully login in the past?

Answer (score 1):

Find `launcher_profiles.json.backup` or `launcher_profiles.json` in your minecraft folder. Search for `authenticationDatabase`, under which there is a `username` field which contains your e-mail address.

Comment: @Penguin Does it work for you now?

Comment: Oh yes, that seems to answer the question now! Sorry if it seemed a bit rude, as I doubted you still used these forums after four years and was meant to address a reader so they are not confused.

Comment: No that wasn't rude at all ... thank you, I had misread the question